# Existence of an oscillating limit involving a logarithm

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to prove that the following limit exists:
$$
\lim_{t\to+\infty}\int_0^1{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}\,\log\left[1 - \sin^2(x t)\,\frac{1 - x^2}{1 + a x^2}\right]},
$$
where $ a $ is a real positive constant.

I have numerical evidence that the above limit does exist, but I have been unable to convincingly show its existence—much less determine its value.

Any help or hint would be much appreciated. Even an upper bound on the limit without explicit proof of its actual existence (which sounds like it may be  not too hard to establish) would be greatly welcome.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT (1/21/2016):**

I found a somewhat satisying solution to the problem some days ago, so I thought I would add it here for posterity.

Recall that, according to the Riemann–Lebesgue lemma,
$$
\hskip{7em}\lim_{t\to+\infty} \int_0^1 \mathrm{d}x \,e^{ixt} f(x) = 0 \hskip{7em}(1)
$$
whenever $ f(x) $ is a $ t $-independent, $ \mathrm{L^1} $-summable function over $ (0,1) $.
Call $ L_a $ the above expression we wish to evaluate. Expand the integrand and swap the integral with the summation and the limit to obtain
$$
\begin{align}
L_a &= -\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty}\lim_{t\to+\infty}\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\left(\frac{e^{ixt} - e^{-ixt}}{2i}\right)^{2k}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+a x^2}\right)^k \\
&= -\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{4^k}{2k \choose k} \int_0^1 \frac{ \mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+a x^2}\right)^k, \\
\end{align}
$$
where I used $ (1) $ to get rid of all the oscillating terms resulting from the Newton expansion of $ \sin^{2k}(xt) $.

Now the $ t $-dependence is gone, and the integral may be evaluated analytically for any $ k $. What results is a series of hypergeometric functions that (as far as I can tell) admits no closed representation for generic $ a $, and must therefore be evaluated numerically.